# Creating a function that shuffles a deck of cards

Tags: python-3.x

So the problem is as follows:

`simpleSHuffle(D)` takes as input list of elements. It should step through the list, at each point exchanging the current element with an element chosen at random from the remainder of the list (including the present element). In other words, if we are considering the third element of `aten` element list, we select an index between 3 and 9, inclusive, and exchange `list[3]` with `list[0]` before advancing to the fourth element of the list and repeating the process. Note that yo will need to use the `randint()` function, which has been imported for you from the random module  at the top of this file

```
def simpleShuffle(D):
n=len(D)-1
for i in range(n):
        r=randin(i,n)
        temp=D[r]
        D[r]=D[i]
        D[i]=temp
return D
```

Above is what I got. Are there any other ways of doing this? Any improvements?

Comment: HI Please refer this page for asking good question which usually get upvoted,which helps in getting good answer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

[`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) should get you what you want

```
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> shuffle(a)
>>> a
[4, 2, 1, 3]
```

Note that `shuffle` shuffles the sequence in place and does not return anything.